# Get the y value for each x in a line (WPF 3D)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have used VS 2019 in Windows 7 to develop a WPF 3D project.

I have created a function(draw a line when drag mouse right button).

I have tried many method but failed to achieve this: when I loop the x in a range, the y on this line is output.

The code I have tried:

```
public void OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs args)      
      {
    try
    {
        if (args.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            currentPoint_2 = args.GetPosition(this);
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = currentPoint_2.X;
            line.Y2 = currentPoint_2.Y;
            line.StrokeThickness = 2;
            canvasOn3D.Children.Add(line);

            foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(-100, 100))
            {
                double y = line.Y1 + ((line.Y2 - line.Y1) * (x - line.X1) 
                            / (line.X2 - line.X1));
                messagebox.show(y);

            }
        }
```

When x = -100, the y value output in my code is 200 , which is not on the line.

May be there's some problem with this line:

```
double y = line.Y1 + ((line.Y2 - line.Y1) * (x - line.X1) 
                        / (line.X2 - line.X1));
```

But I could not tell the error......`

When I debug, I draw a line randomly and X1 = 53, Y1 = 194, X2 = 487, Y2 = 196 in the debug case.

Comment: the formula is correct, although become useless for vertical lines. You should show us which coords have the two points of the line.

Comment: X1 = 53, Y1 = 194, X2 = 487, Y2 = 196 in the debug case.

Comment: these are for an almost-horizontal line: there are 2 pixels vertically for (roughly) 450 pixels horizontally. It means that at -100 is roughly 150 pixels left from X1. But, 150 is 450 / 3, thus it expects a vertical delta of 2 / 3 pixels. By the way, if I make the calculation, it gives 193.29493087557603, which is (roughly) 2 / 3 pixels less than Y1. What is wrong on that?